# Java Parse JSON with LocalDateTime 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: java, json, gson, java-time, datetimeformatter

I have a problem. I am doing a call to my webserver, which returns me a JSON string. In this JSON string, I have a few objects like this:

```
public class Transaction {

    private int id;
    private LocalDateTime datetime;
    private double quantity;
    private double avgPrice;

    public ArrayList<Transaction> parseJsonToList(String StrJSON) {
    
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, (JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime>) (json, type, jsonDeserializationContext) -> {
            try{
                return LocalDateTime.parse(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e){
                return LocalDateTime.parse(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"));
            }
        }).create();
    
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Transaction>>() {}.getType();
    
        return gson.fromJson(StrJSON, listType);
    
    }
    
}
```

Now when I call the `parseJsonToList()` method, I made a GsonBuilder, which should translate the datetime from my JSON to the LocalDateTime attriubtes (with or without micro time). The problem I have now, is that some datetime values are `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. This gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '0000-00-00 00:00:00' could not be parsed at index 19
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2051)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1953)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:493)
    at com.company.Transaction.lambda$parseJsonToList$1(Transaction.java:109)
    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
```

Now I can't change the JSON, so is there a way I can still store it or with a null value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateTimeFormatter#withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT)`

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT);
        String str = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(str, dtf);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
-0001-11-30T00:00
```

Comment: @Vreesie - Replace `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` with `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT)`.